# Service Workers from an iframe for Chrome GCM notifications for web

Tags: iframe, service-worker, chrome-gcm, web-push, push-api

I want to subscribe/ unsubscribe to a service worker to get Chrome GCM Notifications on web through an iframe.

I have a working prototype which works fine while opening it directly on the browser and also from window.open javascript pop up.

But it gives a permission denied error while loading it from an iframe.

What could be wrong here and yes my origin is an http and iframe URL is https.
Why cant an iframe subscribe to notifications.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Works directly but not from an iFrame, even when the origin is https.
getSubscription() does work and returns if a subscription exists, but not subscribe()

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for or other alternate solution for this.

Answer (score 5):

I did a long search and then i got to know that this is not possible any more for security intent. You can't register a service worker from an unsecure domain or sub domain, Even if you are using IFRAME sandbox allow-same-origin then now post Chrome 43 it's not possible to register.
Check out:
https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/700
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489670